# How to extract parameter from pdf file using java code & pdfbox

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, extract, pdfbox

I am doing a java program which is to extract parameter from pdf files. I would like to extract the pdf to get the parameter like

- obj
- endobj
- stream
- endstream
- xref
- trailer
- startxref
- /Page
- /Encrypt
- /ObjStm
- /JS
- /JavaScript
- /AA
- /OpenAction
- /JBIG2Decode
- /RichMedia
- /Launch
- /XFA

parameter:

[image: parameter]

so I wish to get the output shown in the picture below:

[image: convert text]

Comment: So you want to extract the text from the PDF, and then count the occurences?

Comment: @notyou Yes. Do you know how?

Comment: @notyou I am able to do it using pdfid in Kali Linux but I have no idea how to do it using java for my program.

Comment: First of, what you call *"parameters"* is a mixture of syntactical elements (e.g. `obj` and `endobj` enveloping an indirect object) and PDF names (e.g. **Pages** for the type of an inner pages tree node). Furthermore it is not clear where you want to search for these texts, only in the raw file or also inside encrypted or compressed streams.

Comment: You mention the [pdfid](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/#pdfid) tool. It is meant to help identify malicious PDFs. Its author says *"it will also generate false positives"*... I'd say it will _predominantly_ create false positives for common documents produced nowadays.

Comment: @mkl I want to search these from the raw file. I would upload the pdf file into my system, and i need to extract these information from the pdf file. Is there any library that does it? From what I had researched, pdfbox does not extract the information i wanted. :/

Comment: If you want to emulate pdfid functionality, you likely won't find a library doing that for you (unless someone else did that port before). The reason: The author *"decided to keep this program very simple"*, to *"scan a PDF document for a given list of strings and count the occurrences (total and obfuscated) of each word"*. At first glance this can be done by reading a PDF "line by line" and counting occurrences of the identifiers in each line, What it does resolve, though, is what the author calls [name obfuscation](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/04/29/pdf-let-me-count-the-ways/), and...

Comment: ... and it is extremely unlikely you find finished libraries which ignore everything about PDFs but this "obfuscation". On the other hand it is trivial to read PDFs, normalize away those "obfuscations", and then count identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Going by comment above *So you want to extract the text from the PDF, and then count the occurences?*, you can do as follows:

Read the PDF file in:

```
String[] words = null;
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\path\\to\\file.pdf"))) {
    document.getClass();
    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
        words = pdfFileInText.split("\\s+");
    }
}
```

And then print the occurrences of words:

```
Arrays.stream(words)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
       .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v.size()));
```

You may need to tweak this slightly to your own needs.

Comment: Considering the nature of the search strings (syntactical PDF elements and PDF names), I doubt the OP wants to do text extraction.

Comment: @mkl I thought that and I thought I got clarification from the OP in the comments. It may appear not, though.

Comment: I think the OP himself actually is a bit unsure what he is about to do... The tool he mentions in a comment, pdfid, explicitly has been designed *not* to understand PDF syntax, so I wonder why the OP tries to reproduce its working using a library that does...